# How to call the import.io api using a php function?

Tags: php, rest, import.io

I have scraped a few webpages using the desktop app of Import.io and have saved then as APIs , now I want to use it in my webpage to get data from the said API, I am more comfortable with PHP so I would like to know the method to get the data from the API and store it in my variables in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import.io doesn't have a custom a PHP client at the moment, so I would recommend having a look at the API docs: http://api.docs.import.io/#QueryMethods From what you are saying, you are interested in the Query Methods. You can use some kind of PHP REST Library to support calling the API, like: http://phphttpclient.com/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after a bit of studying I finally got it working